# Filtering grid with select

Tags: filter, dropdown

Let's say I have a grid with information about 5000 people.

Also, I have a dropdown with the list of foods above the grid with the label:

```
"Filter people by favorite food"
```

Question:
Should I filter dropdown values to only those represented in the grid?
I mean, let's say I have 30 foods in the dropdown initially, but those 5000 people in the grid only use 5 different foods. Should I limit my dropdown to 10 existing items, this way users will never get an empty grid when filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of filtering is to get a subset of the whole set using information filtering tools which are delivered by system. This is main distinction between [filtering and search](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4752/search-vs-filter-what-is-the-difference), although the border is rather fuzzy (e.g. predictive search).

Also keep in mind, the **secondary filter's role is to inform user about the general set**, presenting its unique values as filter values. Just watching the filter's values could deliver some insights and affect user's decisions.

So the better way is to **limit filter by only existing values**.